# Cloudformation template for steps in Pyspark EMR

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

I am trying to create an EMR cluster using AWS cloudformation.
I am using the following step argument for my EMR Pyspark job where I need to provide multiple .py zip files.

```
EMRStepArgs:
    Description: EMR Step Args
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: "spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,--packages,org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1,--py-files,'s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/jobs.zip\,s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/shared.zip\,s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/libs.zip\,s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/schema.zip',--files,s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/config.json,s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/main.py,--job,cdn,--start_date,'2021-04-14',--end_date,'2021-04-14'"
```

This `EMRStepArgs`  will be provided as an argument to EMR steps in cloudformation .yaml file

What I am getting in the EMR cluster is

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1 --py-files 's3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/jobs.zip s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/shared.zip s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/libs.zip s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/schema.zip' --files s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/config.json s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/main.py --job cdn --start_date '2021-04-14' --end_date '2021-04-14'
```

what I want is

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1 --py-files s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/jobs.zip,s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/shared.zip,s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/libs.zip,s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/schema.zip --files s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/config.json s3://logsetl-emr/py-dist/main.py --job cdn --start_date '2021-04-14' --end_date '2021-04-14'
```

I am not sure how to ignore commas in argument.

Comment: " ignore commas in argument" - what do you mean by this? If you don't want commans, then why did you put it there?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved with defining EMRStepArgs as

```
EMRStepArgs:
    Description: EMR Step Args
    Type: String
    Default: "spark-submit --master yarn --conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true --deploy-mode cluster --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1 --py-files s3://logsetl--emr/py-dist/jobs.zip,s3://logsetl--emr/py-dist/shared.zip,s3://logsetl--emr/py-dist/libs.zip,s3://logsetl--emr/py-dist/schema.zip --files s3://logsetl--emr/py-dist/config.json s3://logsetl--emr/py-dist/main.py --job cdn --start_date '2021-04-14' --end_date '2021-04-14'"
```

and using it in steps like

```
- ActionOnFailure: !Ref EMRActionOnfailure
          HadoopJarStep:
            Args:
              !Split [" ", !Ref EMRStepArgs]
              # Ref: EMRStepArgs

            Jar: command-runner.jar
            MainClass: ""
```